Converting output of cf_xarray to an xarray Dataset with "lat", "lon", "time" dimensions
You can find below the code I have used to convert a shapefile to an xarray dataset using cf_xarray library. What I want to achieve now is having an xarray Dataset with dimensions  "lat", "lon", "time" and the variables listed below, getting rid of the "features" and "nodes" created with the method.
import geopandas as gpd 

shapefile_path = "path/to/shapefile.zip"
shapefile = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

import cf_xarray as cfxr
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

gdfr = shapefile.rename(columns={'date': 'time'}).set_index('time')
ds_raw = gdfr.to_xarray()

ds_uniq = cfxr.geometry.reshape_unique_geometries(ds_raw)
da = ds_uniq["geometry"]
outcf = cfxr.shapely_to_cf(da)
outcf = xr.merge([ds_uniq.drop_vars('geometry'), outcf])


Here is my dataset:
<xarray.Dataset> Size: 23kB
Dimensions:             (features: 74, time: 1, node: 984)
Coordinates:
  * features            (features) int64 592B 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 68 69 70 71 72 73
  * time                (time) datetime64[ns] 8B 2019-03-11
    x                   (node) float64 8kB 48.04 46.92 46.91 ... 50.69 51.12
    y                   (node) float64 8kB 8.781 8.843 9.431 ... 11.4 11.41 11.5
    crd_x               (features) float64 592B 48.04 46.9 44.15 ... 43.31 51.12
    crd_y               (features) float64 592B 8.781 6.884 1.442 ... 11.47 11.5
Dimensions without coordinates: node
Data variables:
    asap0_id            (features, time) int64 592B 156 156 156 ... 156 156 156
    asap2_id            (features, time) int64 592B 4702 4358 4627 ... 4541 4560
    asap0_name          (features, time) object 592B 'Somalia' ... 'Somalia'
    asap2_name          (features, time) object 592B 'Xudun' ... 'Iskushuban'
    w_crop              (features, time) int64 592B 99 99 99 99 ... 99 99 99 99
    w_crop_na           (features, time) object 592B 'No crop/rangeland' ... ...
    w_crop_de           (features, time) object 592B 'Unit not considered in ...
    w_crop_gr           (features, time) int64 592B 5 5 5 5 9 9 ... 5 5 5 5 5 5
    node_count          (features) int64 592B 5 5 5 5 5 6 ... 28 29 35 37 42 45
    geometry_container  float64 8B nan

I have tried to create a multindex and then substituting this with the node dimension, finally unstacking this but the result is not good as the variables have coordinates "features","time" but I want them to have "time","lat","lon" as coordinates.
ds_new = outcf.rename({"x":"lon", "y":"lat"})
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [ds_new.lon.values, ds_new.lat.values], names=['lon', 'lat']
)
ds_new = ds_new.drop_dims("node")
ds_new['node'] = index
reshaped = ds_new.drop_duplicates("node").unstack('node')

